# What does Javascript do (|=, &= and ~)?

Tags: javascript

What do the |=, &= and ~ do?

```
mode |= MyEnum.ROTATE;
mode &= ~MyEnum.RESHAPE;
```

## Update:

Many of the answers simply said their bitwise this and bitwise that which did not help since i did not know what bitwise meant. [Here's a good intro](http://javascript.about.com/library/blbitop.htm).

Comment: Why the down votes? Why would someone want to close this? Is this question not clear?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are bitwise operations.

```
mode |= MyEnum.ROTATE
```

is the same as

```
mode = mode | MyEnum.ROTATE
```

or in other words we are adding ROTATE to the mode.

The secone example removes RESHAPE from the mode

`mode` is a bitmask

Answer (score 2):

These are bitwise operators:

`|=` is bitwise or, which is the same as `mode = mode | MyEnum.ROTATE`

`&=` is bitwise and, which is the same as `mode = mode & MyEnum.ROTATE`

`~` is bitwise not

Comment: Thanks, but i have to give it to the other guy for being first and giving this "in other words" explanation. (+1) for effort.

Answer (score 2):

Those are bitwise operators:

```
mode |= MyEnum.ROTATE;
```

is

```
mode = mode | MyEnum.ROTATE;
```

and

```
mode &= ~MyEnum.RESHAPE;
```

is

```
mode = mode & ~MyEnum.RESHAPE;
```

`|` is bitwise **or**, `&` is bitwise **and**, `~` is **bitwise not**.

Answer (score -1):

```
mode |= MyEnum.ROTATE; is like ---> mode = mode | MyEnum.ROTATE
mode &= ~MyEnum.RESHAPE; is like ---> mode = mode & ~MyEnum.ROTATE;
```

Comment: That is not correct, they are bitwise operators, not logical operators.

Comment: "is like --->  mode & MyEnum.ROTATE". I think there are at lease to aspects missing here.

Comment: @NiklasB. : i lost something on cut and paste.... Is clear that what I want to say is that.

Comment: @Don: It's not clear if you don't know what `&= ~` means, IMHO.

Comment: @Don: This is just the way it works. Downvoting is used to move incorrect answers to the bottom. If an answer is edited, the downvote can be removed afterwards (that's what I did).

Comment: @NiklasB. : yes you.... But not all... However, no problem. I'm her nly for help users :)

Comment: @Don: I simply commented, didnt even downvote you.  I just wanted to point out that your original with `&&` and `||` were incorrect so you could fix it

Comment: @jzworkman : edited just before your comment. I told you: cut and past make my error.